# To change PrintDocument DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize to Custom values and to keep them

Tags: c#, printing

I'm doing the next:

```
docToPrint.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = 
                    new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom", (int)Math.Round(DocWidth / 0.254), (int)Math.Round(DocHeight / 0.254));
```

It converts from mm to inches.
It's ok. When the PrinterPreview Dialog is shown first time it shows the Custom page size.
But when I open pageSetupDialog - it drops all previous and forgets about custom settings.

Generaly my question is Topic.Text + "how?";

Thanks

UPDATE: 
I FOUND THE SOLUTION. AS I HAVE REPUTATION<100 = have to wait 24 hrs to submit the ANSWER.

That was not easy to understand.

Comment: Try also changing the PaperSource to a custom one (RawKind of Custom)

Comment: when PrintDoc is shown 1-st time - it has custom size as preset from code. on that preview page there's PageSettings dialog button. when pressed - it shows Custom, but.. even if i do not change anything and press Ok, it switches view back to A4.

Comment: The dialog is implemented by the printer driver.  Anything is possible.  Or rather, most is impossible.  If you already created a custom page size then there's no point in displaying the dialog, you customized the printer's default page sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is - do this on BeginPrint event.